# Splitting words in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

For one of my programming assignments at uni, I need to create a vb program that takes in a word and makes it plural. we then have to write about the difficulties we face etc.
I'm just trying to work out how to go about this. From what I can see, you first must split the word down into it's characters, then identify what the what the last character of the string is. From there I think it's a case of a load of if statements which use the string.join operator to add things like "s" on the end. the joining up seems fairly simple, but it's how to split the input word down and identify the last characters that's bugging me.
I must mention, I'm only on my first year at uni, so I'm not very advanced in programming at all, so if you can help, please make it understandable to someone who has a limited knowledge if at all possible!

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

Comment: A string is an array of characters.  You can index into the array using the length - 1 to get the last character.  Or using Linq, you can use the .Last() extension method to get the last character.  Lots of different ways.  But you really don't want to do that, anyhow.  Sit down with a pen and paper and a list of random words.  In turn, make them plural.  How do YOU do it?  Look for patterns in your actions, and in the words.  Identifying those patterns becomes your algorithm.  Once you have your algorithm, you can work on your code.

Comment: There are a load of string operations that can help with this. Check out all the methods listed on MSDN for the string class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What is your specific problem ? Can we see some code ?

Comment: I don't have any code yet as I have very little idea of how to start. I have some basic pseudocode written down but basically just the if statements. I didn't really know how to alter the input word to output the new plural form of the word without some very over the top and long way. thanks for the help though :)

Comment: Write down on paper, in english each step of the process. Make sure you have dealt with all the possibilities of word endings,case etc then code those steps.And dont forget what to do if the word can't be pluralized

Comment: oh and have a look at [ask] - Stack overflow isn't really a code writing service -tho sometimes we take pity :) You should really be applying what you've learned about planning a program. Then write code. If you're still stuck, come and see us with the code you've tried so far.

Comment: I know it's not, I wouldn't normally ask, but I was really stuck on this one. it was kind of a last resort to be honest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Mike and Will said there are a lot of possibilities, this code is just for some cases, it uses `If` statements, however a `Case` statement might be better

```
  Protected Sub btnPlural_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlural.Click
    Dim strWord As String
    Dim lastLetter As String
    Dim secondlast As String


    If txtWord.Text <> "" Then
        strWord = txtWord.Text
        lastLetter = GetChar(strWord, strWord.Length)
        secondlast = GetChar(strWord, strWord.Length - 1)
        If lastLetter = "r" Or lastLetter = "p" Or lastLetter = "t" Then
            strWord = strWord + "s"
            lblPlural.Text = strWord
        End If
        If lastLetter = "e" Then
            If secondlast = "f" Then
                strWord = strWord.Substring(0, strWord.Length - 2) + "ves"
                lblPlural.Text = strWord
            Else
                strWord = strWord + "s"
                lblPlural.Text = strWord
            End If

        End If

        If lastLetter = "x" Then
            strWord = strWord + "es"
            lblPlural.Text = strWord
        End If
        If lastLetter = "h" Then
            If secondlast = "c" Then
                strWord = strWord + "es"
                lblPlural.Text = strWord
            Else
                strWord = strWord + "s"
                lblPlural.Text = strWord
            End If
        End If

        If lastLetter = "y" Then
            If secondlast = "t" Or secondlast = "d" Or secondlast = "n" Then
                strWord = strWord.Substring(0, strWord.Length - 1) + "ies"
                lblPlural.Text = strWord
            ElseIf secondlast = "e" Or secondlast = "a" Or secondlast = "o" Then
                strWord = strWord + "s"
                lblPlural.Text = strWord
            End If
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, so much. that's cleared it up a lot! My issue was that the tutor hadn't really pointed us anywhere near the answer, so with a few modifications that'll do the trick! thanks so much!

Comment: @AndrewRichardson If my answer did help you, you could mark it as accepted answer, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add an "s" character to the end of a string

```
Dim myString As String = "Shoe"
myString += "s"
'myString is now "Shoes"
```

Or do you want to check if the last character is already an "s", change "cutey" to "cuties", etc?

Comment: At some level an exception list is going to be required, since the plural of Octopus is Octopi, and the plural of Sheep is Sheep. I guess if the word is not in a researched exception list, then you'd have to SELECT CASE RIGHT(str, 3), then last 2 chars, then last one. I'm actually not sure whether you even need to scan 3 or 2, but a dictionary might help.

Comment: I would say the recommended way would be to use `&=` to concat a string to itself

Comment: There are open source dictionaries available online too with plurals, plus there are some obscure rules beyond simply adding 's' which may help before getting to the list of exceptions. Incidentally, iirc the plural of 'Octopus' is 'Octopuses' or 'Octopodes', but 'Octopi' is mixing up Greek and Latin.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a topic just about adding 's' character to the End I would suggest to use `String.Format` and add 's' :

```
Public Function pluralize(ByVal DesignString AS String) AS String   

       Return String.Format("{0}s",DesignString) ' ex : Shoe -> Shoes

End Function
```

Hop this can be helpul for you.